# Answer for Question With Bounty is in Comments

Tags: support, bounty

Recently, I added a bounty to the below linked question (asked by me), and in the process, someone correctly answered my question, in the comments, rather than posting it as an actual answer. I would like to award the bounty to the person who posted the comment, but I don't see a way to do that when they have only commented and not posted an actual answer.

I've replied to the comment, letting the user know that I'll give them the bounty once they've posted it as an answer, but I haven't yet gotten a response. I don't want to post an answer myself, because the other user deserves the credit, but I don't want the post to go unanswered as well, so that others who have the same issue I did might be able to find it.

How do I handle this situation?

Question that I asked:

- [Windows Remote Management Over Untrusted Domains](https://serverfault.com/questions/696321/windows-remote-management-over-untrusted-domains)

Comment: That's not really an answer, and if it were posted as such it would be converted to a comment or deleted.

Comment: Agreed; however, once the user posted that as an answer, my intention was to edit it with more detail. I still feel as though he should get the credit, because I wouldn't have checked out that link if he hadn't of posted it. I guess though, in this case, I should just answer my own question, with detail from that link? What happens to the bounty if I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only wait and hope the user writes an answer, mods can't convert comments to answers.

If he doesn't answer and no one else (except you) posts an answer, the bounty is lost, as you can't award the bounty to yourself.

Comment: That's what I figured. I'll wait then until the bounty expires and if he hasn't posted it as an answer by then, I'll post the answer. I'm not worried about the bounty points myself...I'm just glad I got an answer!